# How to "Unstack" a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

My first question here. I did try to search a similar question and answer but somehow did not return exactly what I was after.

I have an original table like the following. The Forecast volumes are stacked up by the period.

I was trying to "Unstack" the table to have a main column for products and the forecast volumes in each different column for different period.

Original table:

| Product | Period | Forecast Volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | Jan-21 | 500 |
| Product2 | Jan-21 | 200 |
| Product3 | Jan-21 | 300 |
| Product1 | Feb-21 | 400 |
| Product3 | Feb-21 | 500 |
| Product1 | Mar-21 | 120 |
| Product2 | Mar-21 | 50 |
| Product3 | Mar-21 | 180 |
| Product4 | Mar-21 | 200 |

Desire table:

| Product | Jan-21 | Feb-21 | Mar-21 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Product1 | 500 | 400 | 120 |
| Product2 | 200 |  | 50 |
| Product3 | 300 | 500 | 180 |
| Product4 |  |  | 200 |

I have attempted to first, create a table with a column of all the unique product names. Then keep joining the table for the volumes of each month. I was able to do for two months But it's not scalable if there are many periods.

I use MySQL but solutions of any application will help.  I can manage to convert the syntax.
Thanks.

Comment: This is PIVOT. Not supported in MySQL. Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: Search for past answers with [these tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql%2bpivot-table?tab=Votes).  This is a pretty common question.

Comment: Thanks everyone.  There is   a similar question I have found the answer.